# Generate data to fill database only where unique for a given column

Tags: php, mysql

I know that title sounds confusing - let me explain the situation. I have a table called `hands`. Each row in this table is a specific combination of 4 playing cards from a deck of cards, but the hand itself is not unique. What IS unique is the specific combination of `hand` + `sim_id`. The table looks like this:

```
hand / sim_id / percent
AsKsQdJd / 346 / 100
```

There are 270,000 unique combinations of 4 playing cards, but not every unique combination is currently stored in the database. The `percent` column displays what percent of the time the player should play that specific hand. When I imported, I only imported hands with `percent > 0`.

Now, I want to retroactively add ALL combinations to the database for each sim_id. In other words, for all unique 4-card combinations of `hand` for a given `sim_id` that are NOT currently in the database,  I want to add them with `percent = 0`.

I can think of a lot of slow and dumb ways to do this, like literally looping through all possible combinations and checking if they exist for all possible sim_ids, but the database is currently  60 million rows and this update will bring it to >200 million, so time is definitely of the essence for this operation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use an unique index on both fields : ``UNIQUE `unique_idx` (hand, sim_id)``

Comment: However, are `AsKsQdJd` and `KsQdJdAs` supposed to be differents ?

Comment: I would start by normalizing the schema. There should be a table with all suits, another one with all ranks and a linking table between players and cards. Then you can effectively use set operations where a relational database is good at.

Comment: @Cid No, they are not different. Only unique combinations are stored, and the unique combinations are formed according to a specific pattern (Ace > King > Queen, Spade > Diamond > Club, etc.)

Comment: @stickybit Can you expand on what you mean by 'linking table between players and cards.' There is no link between a player and cards. All players share the same database of static information.

Comment: @Cid With regards to the unique index on both fields - is the idea that I could then try and import all 270k combos for each sim_id and it would ignore existing hands because they are non-unique?

Comment: @user393466: A table with a foreign key pointing to the suit, another pointing to the rank and a third pointing to the player. Every row in it expresses a card a player holds.